# ruby-thor calling multiple classes in a gem executable

Tags: ruby, thor

I am learning ruby and thor.. and I am stuck here:

I have two classes in a module (both use Thor). I am able to use only one in the gem executable. When I add both like below and run it, I `get Could not find command "hello".`

```
Test::HammerOfTheGods.start(ARGV)
Test::Git.start(ARGV)
```

Comment: How do you intend both of the different classes to work together? Do you want all the commands from each to be available? If so, can you just use a single class? Thor isn't designed to work this way. The reason you're getting the error is because the first time you call `.start`, an error will be thrown if the command isn't found.

Comment: @MichaelMior thank you! Yes, I want all the commands to work. Didnt know that it is not supported.

Comment: If you're worried about having a particularly long class definition, you can separate the definition of each command into separate files but using the same class.

Comment: that worked.. created separate file but definitions  under same class. Thanks!

Comment: Posted as answer so this can be resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you intend both of the different classes to work together? Do you want all the commands from each to be available? If so, can you just use a single class? Thor isn't designed to work this way. The reason you're getting the error is because the first time you call .start, an error will be thrown if the command isn't found.

If you're worried about having a particularly long class definition, you can separate the definition of each command into separate files but using the same class.